# Add dynamic overlays from array

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet

I am trying to add new layers to the map using the leaflet. First I create the layers by a form then I put the elements related to their relationship. The problem is that to add a new layer to the overlayers object is using static code, and I wanted to use all the layers that I am creating and are downloaded from the database. Does anyone have an idea?

```
var tipo1 = L.layerGroup();
var tipo2 = L.layerGroup();

var overlayers = {
  "Tipo 1": tipo1,
  "Tipo 2": tipo2
};
```

This example works. This is how it should be used. But in my case, instead of using `tipo1` and `tipo2` ... I would have one or more types coming from a database, and wanted to add to overlayers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't post much code, but assuming you're using a Layers control, you can add layers dynamically - eg

```
var myLayersControl = L.control.layers(null, null).addTo(map);
var myNewLayer = L.layerGroup();
myLayersControl.addOverlay(myNewLayer, "Description");
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, gave to implement in this format.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own featureGroup class - something like:

```
    L.Overlayers = L.FeatureGroup.extend({
      initialize: function(options) {
        L.setOptions(this, options);
        L.FeatureGroup.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);
      },

      onAdd: function(map) {
        L.FeatureGroup.prototype.onAdd.call(this, map);

        this._map = map;

        this.on("layeradd", this._doThingsHere, this);
        this.on("layerremove", this._stopDoingThingsHere, this);
      },

      onRemove: function() {
        this.off("layeradd", this._doThingsHere, this);
        this.off("layerremove", this._stopDoingThingsHere, this);
      },
   });
```

If you instantiate an empty instance of it on the map:

```
var group = new L.Overlayers().addTo(map);
```

Then when your data layer loads, you can dynamically add it to the group:

```
group.addLayer(tipo1);
```

This will trigger `layeradd` and give you access to the layer via `e.layer`

From there you have full access to the layer and map.

You can do things like subgroup them into LayerGroups and organize them, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try to use it in another part of the code.